# WPF Richtextbox search much slower when Read-Write

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have implemented a Find command for the WPF Richtextbox.  I have two instances of Richtextboxes. The first is writable.  The second is not. In the read-only richtextbox,
IsDocumentEnabled = true and IsReadOnly = true.

Both richtextboxes have the same text, about 1000 characters.

Searching for a string in the first richtextbox takes 18 seconds. In the readonly one, with the exact same text and the exact same code, the search takes 4 seconds.  Thinking it might be items being added to the Undo stack, I disabled Undo in the first one to see if it would improve performance but it did not.

Does anyone have advice or ideas why there is such a major difference in the performance between the read-write richtextbox and the readonly richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

The result you are reporting is perfectly logical: search (Find) operation on `ReadOnly=true` `RichTextBox` is expected to be much faster than on writable (`ReadOnly=false`) control due to significant programmatic overhead added to writable control. In addition to 'Undo" functionality it may be also dealing with the need for concurrency management, change event handling, etc. Regarding the performance improvement: set `ReadOnly=true` as a default, and "unlock" RichTextBox control (set ReadOnly=false, or something like: `rtf.ReadOnly= (bool)chkBoxLock.IsChecked` ) only if needed.
Rgds,